# Adding elements to an array and assigning it to same object

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks like this.

```
array([[ 1],
       [ 5],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [10]])
```

I need to iterate through each of the element in the array and create this

```
[1 1]
[5 2]
[3 3]
[4 4]
[10  5]
```

I am able to print it this way using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(arr2)): 
    print(np.append(arr2[i],i+1))
```

But I am not able to append this new element on the actual array itself. When I try to assign np.append(arr2[i],i+1) to arr2[i], it throws an error.

```
for i in range(len(arr2)): 
        arr2[i]=np.append(arr2[i],i+1)
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For practical matters, the size of a numpy array is fixed.

That said, there is a `resize` method, but it has a couple of restrictions:

1) It does not have ND semantics:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1], [ 5], [ 3], [ 4], [10]])
>>> 
>>> x.resize((5, 2))
>>> 
>>> x
array([[ 1,  5],
       [ 3,  4],
       [10,  0],
       [ 0,  0],
       [ 0,  0]])
```

2) It often does not work:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1], [ 5], [ 3], [ 4], [10]])
>>> 
>>> x
array([[ 1],
       [ 5],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [10]])
>>> 
>>> x.resize((5, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.  Use the resize function
```

3) Where it works it often allocates a new  data buffer:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1], [ 5], [ 3], [ 4], [10]])
>>> 
>>> x.ctypes.data
30384064
>>> 
>>> x.resize((5, 2))
>>> 
>>> x.ctypes.data
31463392
```

So you are probably better off creating a new object:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1], [ 5], [ 3], [ 4], [10]])
>>> np.c_[x, 1:6]
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 5,  2],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 4,  4],
       [10,  5]])
```

If you absolutely want the new data in the old object you could do something like

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1], [ 5], [ 3], [ 4], [10]])
>>> y = x
>>> 
>>> x.resize((5, 2), refcheck=False)
>>> x[...] = np.c_[x.ravel()[:5], 1:6]
>>> 
>>> y
array([[ 1,  1],
       [ 5,  2],
       [ 3,  3],
       [ 4,  4],
       [10,  5]])
```

but you must be aware that switching off refchecking is dangerous:

```
>>> x = np.array([[ 1], [ 5], [ 3], [ 4], [10]])
>>> y = x[::2]
>>> 
>>> x.resize((5, 2), refcheck=False)
>>> 
>>> y
array([[29006928],
       [       0],
       [      48]])
```

As you can see `y` still references the now invalid data buffer of `x` before resizing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with simple list comprehension :

```
[a+[i+1] for i,a in enumerate(array)]
```